# Replace all unwanted semicolon outside the quote or double quotes

Tags: awk, sed

I'm not quite good at bash.
I have generated PSQL file from Excel with python
to run psql in bash script.

I would like to replace all semicolon outside the quote or double quotes

```
SELECT *; FROM table ;WHERE description =';';

SELECT *; FROM table ;WHERE; description like "%;%";

SELECT *; FROM table ;;WHERE description like ";?";
```

THE Result should except semicolon in all type of quote/double quotes like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description =';'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like "%;%"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like ";?"
```

Here's what I tried

```
sed "s/.*;.*\(\'\;'\)//g" a.sql
```

seem it does nothing

```
SELECT *; FROM table ;WHERE description =';';

SELECT *; FROM table ;WHERE; description like "%;%";

SELECT *; FROM table ;;WHERE description like ";?";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a gnu awk solution using `FPAT`:

```sh
awk -v OFS= -v FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\"]+" '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (!($i ~ /["\047]/)) gsub(/;/, "", $i)
} 1' file

SELECT * FROM table WHERE description =';'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like "%;%"
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like ";?"
```

**`FPAT` regex details:**

- `\"[^\"]*\"`: Match a double quoted string
- `|`: OR
- `'[^']*'`: Match a single quoted string
- `|`: OR
- `[^'\"]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that are not `'` and `"`
- `if (!($i ~ /["\047]/)) gsub(/;/, "", $i)`: Removes `;` if field doesn't start with `"` or `'`

---

Alternatively use this `perl` command line:

```sh
perl -pe 's/((["\047])(?:\\.|[^"\047])*\2)|;/$1/g' file

SELECT * FROM table WHERE description =';'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like "%;%"
SELECT * FROM table WHERE description like ";?"
```

Comment: yes Thank you, It's worked, and try to understand this. Can you explain more on 047 since from ASCII table, it would only cover Single quote which one's handle on case that start with Double quote?

Comment: I have `["\047]` in bracket expression which mean match `"` or `'`

Comment: ok, I got it.
awk -v OFS= -v FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\"]+" '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if (!($i ~ /["\047]/)) gsub(/;/, "", $i)
} 1' a.sql > tmp &&  mv tmp a.sql